# Sqoop incremental import to S3 Wrong FS error

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, sqoop

When using the `--incremental append` flag in the `sqoop import`, the job will fail.

`ERROR tool.ImportTool: Imported Failed: Wrong FS: s3n://<api_key>:<api_secret>@bucket/folder/`

Here is the full command:

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:postgresql://someplace.net:12345/db --warehouse-dir s3n://<key>:<private>@bucket/folder/ --table my_table --hive-drop-import-delims --escaped-by "\\" --username root --password safepass -m 2 --split-by id  --incremental append --check-column id`

The exact same command without the `--incremental' and`--check-column` work without any error and upload to the correct s3 directory as expected. I want to be able to run an incremental import and have it uploaded to s3.

I'm using Sqoop 1.4.1-cdh4.1.3

Full output:

```
13/02/23 12:02:10 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Loaded manager factory: com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory
13/02/23 12:02:10 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Trying ManagerFactory: com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory
13/02/23 12:02:10 DEBUG manager.DefaultManagerFactory: Trying with scheme: jdbc:postgresql:
13/02/23 12:02:10 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
13/02/23 12:02:10 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Instantiated ConnManager org.apache.sqoop.manager.PostgresqlManager@5239443f
13/02/23 12:02:10 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
13/02/23 12:02:10 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: No connection paramenters specified. Using regular API for making connection.
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Using fetchSize for next query: 1000
13/02/23 12:02:11 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM "fan_pages_facebookpage" AS t LIMIT 1
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.ClassWriter: selected columns:
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.ClassWriter:   id
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.ClassWriter:   name
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.ClassWriter:   page_id
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.ClassWriter:   category_id
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.ClassWriter:   is_published
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.ClassWriter:   website
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.ClassWriter:   username
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.ClassWriter:   description
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.ClassWriter:   about
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.ClassWriter:   can_post
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.ClassWriter:   talking_about_count
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.ClassWriter:   link
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.ClassWriter:   picture
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.ClassWriter:   last_synced_date
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.ClassWriter:   fans
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.ClassWriter: Writing source file: /tmp/sqoop-hdfs/compile/ecf12c8875f71c2d98db0ccde2516629/fan_pages_facebookpage.java
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.ClassWriter: Table name: fan_pages_facebookpage
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.ClassWriter: Columns: id:4, name:12, page_id:12, category_id:4, is_published:-7, website:12, username:12, description:12, about:12, can_post:-7, talking_about_count:4, link:12, picture:12, last_synced_date:93, fans:4, 
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.ClassWriter: sourceFilename is fan_pages_facebookpage.java
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.CompilationManager: Found existing /tmp/sqoop-hdfs/compile/ecf12c8875f71c2d98db0ccde2516629/
13/02/23 12:02:11 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_HOME is /usr/lib/hadoop
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.CompilationManager: Adding source file: /tmp/sqoop-hdfs/compile/ecf12c8875f71c2d98db0ccde2516629/fan_pages_facebookpage.java
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.CompilationManager: Invoking javac with args:
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.CompilationManager:   -sourcepath
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.CompilationManager:   /tmp/sqoop-hdfs/compile/ecf12c8875f71c2d98db0ccde2516629/
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.CompilationManager:   -d
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.CompilationManager:   /tmp/sqoop-hdfs/compile/ecf12c8875f71c2d98db0ccde2516629/
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.CompilationManager:   -classpath
13/02/23 12:02:11 DEBUG orm.CompilationManager:   /etc/hadoop/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/kfs-0.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/junit-4.8.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/avro-1.7.1.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/zookeeper-3.4.3-cdh4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-annotations-2.0.0-cdh4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-annotations.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-auth.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-auth-2.0.0-cdh4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.1.3-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/sqoop/conf:/etc/zookeeper::/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/ant-eclipse-1.0-jvm1.2.jar:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/avro-1.7.1.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/avro-ipc-1.7.1.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/avro-mapred-1.7.1.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/netty-3.4.0.Final.jar:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/sqoop/postgresql-9.0-802.jdbc4.jar:/usr/lib/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.1-cdh4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/sqoop/sqoop-test-1.4.1-cdh4.1.3.jar::/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/zookeeper-3.4.3-cdh4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs-2.0.0-cdh4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs-2.0.0-cdh4.1.3-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/avro-1.7.1.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/netty-3.2.4.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.0.0-cdh4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.0.0-cdh4.1.3-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-site-2.0.0-cdh4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-api-2.0.0-cdh4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.0.0-cdh4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.0.0-cdh4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-site.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-api.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-common-2.0.0-cdh4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.0.0-cdh4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.0.0-cdh4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.0.0-cdh4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/aspectjtools-1.6.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/avro-compiler-1.7.1.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/kfs-0.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/kfs-0.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/junit-4.8.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/aspectjrt-1.6.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.1.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/hadoop-fairscheduler-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.3-tools.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.3-examples.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-examples-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-tools.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-ant.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-test-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.3-ant.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-core.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-tools-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-core-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.3-test.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-test.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.3-core.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-examples.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-ant-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-core-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.1-cdh4.1.3.jar
Note: /tmp/sqoop-hdfs/compile/ecf12c8875f71c2d98db0ccde2516629/fan_pages_facebookpage.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
13/02/23 12:02:19 DEBUG orm.CompilationManager: Could not rename /tmp/sqoop-hdfs/compile/ecf12c8875f71c2d98db0ccde2516629/fan_pages_facebookpage.java to /home/users/alexkehayias/./fan_pages_facebookpage.java
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/users/alexkehayias/./fan_pages_facebookpage.java (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:209)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:160)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.doCopyFile(FileUtils.java:936)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:888)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:835)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveFile(FileUtils.java:2385)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.CompilationManager.compile(CompilationManager.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:83)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:390)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:476)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:57)
13/02/23 12:02:19 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-hdfs/compile/ecf12c8875f71c2d98db0ccde2516629/fan_pages_facebookpage.jar
13/02/23 12:02:19 DEBUG orm.CompilationManager: Scanning for .class files in directory: /tmp/sqoop-hdfs/compile/ecf12c8875f71c2d98db0ccde2516629
13/02/23 12:02:19 DEBUG orm.CompilationManager: Got classfile: /tmp/sqoop-hdfs/compile/ecf12c8875f71c2d98db0ccde2516629/fan_pages_facebookpage.class -> fan_pages_facebookpage.class
13/02/23 12:02:19 DEBUG orm.CompilationManager: Finished writing jar file /tmp/sqoop-hdfs/compile/ecf12c8875f71c2d98db0ccde2516629/fan_pages_facebookpage.jar
13/02/23 12:02:19 DEBUG tool.ImportTool: Using temporary folder: 23120219788fan_pages_facebookpage
13/02/23 12:02:19 INFO tool.ImportTool: Maximal id query for free form incremental import: SELECT MAX(id) FROM fan_pages_facebookpage
13/02/23 12:02:19 INFO tool.ImportTool: Incremental import based on column "id"
13/02/23 12:02:19 INFO tool.ImportTool: Upper bound value: 2178
13/02/23 12:02:19 WARN manager.PostgresqlManager: It looks like you are importing from postgresql.
13/02/23 12:02:19 WARN manager.PostgresqlManager: This transfer can be faster! Use the --direct
13/02/23 12:02:19 WARN manager.PostgresqlManager: option to exercise a postgresql-specific fast path.
13/02/23 12:02:19 DEBUG manager.CatalogQueryManager: Retrieving primary key for table 'fan_pages_facebookpage' with query SELECT col.ATTNAME FROM PG_CATALOG.PG_NAMESPACE sch,   PG_CATALOG.PG_CLASS tab, PG_CATALOG.PG_ATTRIBUTE col,   PG_CATALOG.PG_INDEX ind WHERE sch.OID = tab.RELNAMESPACE   AND tab.OID = col.ATTRELID   AND tab.OID = ind.INDRELID   AND sch.NSPNAME = (SELECT CURRENT_SCHEMA())   AND tab.RELNAME = 'fan_pages_facebookpage'   AND col.ATTNUM = ANY(ind.INDKEY)   AND ind.INDISPRIMARY
13/02/23 12:02:19 DEBUG manager.CatalogQueryManager: Retrieving primary key for table 'fan_pages_facebookpage' with query SELECT col.ATTNAME FROM PG_CATALOG.PG_NAMESPACE sch,   PG_CATALOG.PG_CLASS tab, PG_CATALOG.PG_ATTRIBUTE col,   PG_CATALOG.PG_INDEX ind WHERE sch.OID = tab.RELNAMESPACE   AND tab.OID = col.ATTRELID   AND tab.OID = ind.INDRELID   AND sch.NSPNAME = (SELECT CURRENT_SCHEMA())   AND tab.RELNAME = 'fan_pages_facebookpage'   AND col.ATTNUM = ANY(ind.INDKEY)   AND ind.INDISPRIMARY
13/02/23 12:02:19 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of fan_pages_facebookpage
13/02/23 12:02:20 DEBUG mapreduce.DataDrivenImportJob: Using table class: fan_pages_facebookpage
13/02/23 12:02:20 DEBUG mapreduce.DataDrivenImportJob: Using InputFormat: class com.cloudera.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat
13/02/23 12:02:21 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/usr/lib/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.1-cdh4.1.3.jar
13/02/23 12:02:21 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/usr/lib/sqoop/postgresql-9.0-802.jdbc4.jar
13/02/23 12:02:21 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/usr/lib/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.1-cdh4.1.3.jar
13/02/23 12:02:21 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/usr/lib/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.1-cdh4.1.3.jar
13/02/23 12:02:21 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar
13/02/23 12:02:21 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/netty-3.4.0.Final.jar
13/02/23 12:02:21 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar
13/02/23 12:02:21 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar
13/02/23 12:02:21 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar
13/02/23 12:02:21 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar
13/02/23 12:02:21 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar
13/02/23 12:02:21 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar
13/02/23 12:02:21 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar
13/02/23 12:02:21 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar
13/02/23 12:02:21 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/ant-eclipse-1.0-jvm1.2.jar
13/02/23 12:02:21 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/avro-mapred-1.7.1.cloudera.2.jar
13/02/23 12:02:21 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/avro-1.7.1.cloudera.2.jar
13/02/23 12:02:21 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/avro-ipc-1.7.1.cloudera.2.jar
13/02/23 12:02:24 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/02/23 12:02:26 INFO db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: BoundingValsQuery: SELECT MIN("id"), MAX("id") FROM "fan_pages_facebookpage" WHERE ( "id" <= 2178 )
13/02/23 12:02:26 DEBUG db.IntegerSplitter: Splits: [                           1 to                        2,178] into 4 parts
13/02/23 12:02:26 DEBUG db.IntegerSplitter:                            1
13/02/23 12:02:26 DEBUG db.IntegerSplitter:                          546
13/02/23 12:02:26 DEBUG db.IntegerSplitter:                        1,090
13/02/23 12:02:26 DEBUG db.IntegerSplitter:                        1,634
13/02/23 12:02:26 DEBUG db.IntegerSplitter:                        2,178
13/02/23 12:02:27 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201302231136_0003
13/02/23 12:02:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/02/23 12:02:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 25% reduce 0%
13/02/23 12:02:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 50% reduce 0%
13/02/23 12:03:03 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201302231136_0003
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 23
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File System Counters
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of bytes read=0
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of bytes written=667342
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of read operations=0
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of large read operations=0
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of write operations=0
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of bytes read=412
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of bytes written=1165120
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of read operations=4
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of write operations=4
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=4
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=64432
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=1935
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=1935
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Input split bytes=412
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=0
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=3110
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=507801600
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=3964473344
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=108265472
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 50.0965 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
13/02/23 12:03:11 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 1935 records.
13/02/23 12:03:11 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Imported Failed: Wrong FS: s3n://auth:secret@bucket/folder, expected: hdfs://ec2-111-11-11-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8020
```

Comment: I should note that I was also able to get the append command to work locally to an s3 folder specified in the `warehouse-dir`, but not on a cluster.

Comment: Would be great if you could share entire sqoop output generated with parameter --verbose.

Answer (score 3):

The reason this is happening is that Sqoop writes files to a temporary directory when in "incremental" mode. This is to avoid partial writes to the final destination directory. After writing everything to the temp directory, it will issue a "rename" for each file to get them into the final destination directory, which obviously won't work across filesystems (HDFS -> S3).

The way to make this work is to make Sqoop use S3 for the temporary directory as well. Before issuing the job, set the system property that Sqoop relies on as the base for the temporary files (see [AppendUtils](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/util/AppendUtils.java)):

```
System.setProperty("sqoop.test.import.rootDir", <AUTHENTICATED_S3N_URL>);
```

Also, when renaming the files, Sqoop gets a handle on the FS by getting the default FS from the Hadoop config, so you'll also need to set this to S3N:

```
FileSystem.setDefaultUri(configuration, <AUTHENTICATED_S3N_URL>);
```

It's not pretty, but it works.